# How does Mint.com Budget Once work?

Tags: mint.com

Can someone explain to me how budget once works on mint.com. I have set a budget to spend $1500 by December 2012. It says "We’ll set aside $500 each month for Snowboard Gear and expect an expense of $1,500 in December 2012."

It then shows up on my budget list saying "$0 spent, $500 set aside this month." However this does not change my number on the right that gets calculated based on income and other budgets. Which is the "You've budgeted..." $x,xxx income and $x,xxx spending. However, I would expect $500 to be added to the $x,xxx spending amount so that I can see how much money I really should have left over at the end of the month.

Is this a bug or am I just mistaken on how this feature works?
[image]
[image]

If you add up all the budgets, including the $500 for Snowboard Gear, it should be $2880 however, it says I'm only budgeting $2380

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 48 times.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an ancient question. Things have changed a lot on the Internet since it was created. It's unlikely that Community user continue bumping this question will help anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Since there has been no activity here I will try answering. It looks like this is probably a bug. I just tried adding a future item to my budget list and the per month budget **is** getting reflected in my total on the right.

If you are still experiencing a problem with the totals not lining up I would submit a bug: https://www.mint.com/help/

Comment: I already posted the same thread on their forums. They responded however, they did not answer my question. That is interesting that yours works though.